# Set text to textfield of table Cell in objective c outside UITableView delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am new to objective C,and have made a demo app.

In this app I am having a UITableView which contains textField.When I taps a button(sign in using Facebook), after successfully login from Facebook it come back to my TableView screen,at that time i want to set values came from Facebook response to UITableView's textFields, but I am unable to do it as TableView's delegate method is calling only once.

Can anybody please help me to set text to tableView's textField outside its delegate method?

**code**

```
 NSString *cellIdentifier = [[signInTableData objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"cellIdentifier"];

 signUpCustomCell *cell = (signUpCustomCell *)[signUpTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 //NSLog(@"=====my username cell====%@",indexPath);
 if(cell == nil)
 {
    cell = (signUpCustomCell *)[[signUpCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.tableField.delegate = self;

 CGRect frmTxt = cell.tableField.frame;
 frmTxt.size.width = signUpTable.frame.size.width + TRAIL_MARGIN_CELL_CONTENT;
 cell.tableField.frame = frmTxt;
 cell.tableField.text = @"hello test";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know at which row your `UITextField` is then you can query `UITableView` for a cell at given `IndexPath`.

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
```

You'll need to cast that cell to what ever custom cell you are using to access the `UITextField` inside and your custom `UITableViewCell` should have a property that points to the `UITextField` or a method that would update the text.

`-(void)viewWillAppear` or `-(void)viewDidApper` overrides in your `UIViewController` subclass could be the places to do that, after you have loaded your data to the `UITableView`.

Comment: i have done like this, `NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];
                                          UITableViewCell *cell = [self->tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
                                          cell.tableField.text =email;` but it says tableField is not found on object type of controller.

Comment: index path i know is 2.and have textField inside it,Please tell me to set text to it.

Comment: @ConcentratedH2SO4 1) Are you sure you are in section 1 (that implies you have more than one section)? 2) You either need to cast that cell to your custom cell if you are using a custom cell. If you don't use a custom cell you need to set a tag to `UITextField` in InterfaceBuilder and find it from cell by using `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:@"<your tag>"]`. I would suggest using custom cell.

Comment: WAit,Please see my updated question.so that u can help me.i am posting some code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set values into `UITextField` in delegate 
`cellForRowAtIndexPath` as it is rendered for every cell of `UITableView`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourcellidentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"yourcellidentifier"] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    cell.yourTextView.text= textforRow;
    return cell;
}
```